# Allowing access to a custom folder in drupal root with NGINX

Tags: nginx, drupal

Is there a way to allow access to extra custom folders on my drupal installation ? I try to use drupalgap and it requires public access to a custom created directory. I want to know what is the nginx rule that allows me to do so. I am using BOA for running my server. Thanks

Comment: You should provide your nginx conf.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a standard nginx conf for your Drupal, you should have a try_files that will serve any physical files of the Drupal folder...
But maybe you're speaking about PHP scripts ?